# Write list to existing excel file while iterating columns and rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I am attempting to write a list into an existing Excel file. The list would start at column number 5 and print each list value every four columns (next would be in column 9). Then, after the each item in the list has been written into excel, the list will be emptied and new data will be appended. The program then needs to write to the exact same columns as before, but shifted down a row.

I've tried several methods but have not been able to get anything to work. I also need the Excel file to be saved after writing into each row, and wasn't sure if ExcelWriter did this automatically or not. Here is the current code I have that is nonfunctional.

```
def start_buy_monitoring():
    excel_file = "MarketBots (1).xlsx"
    row_inc = 0

    excel_output = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Buff163AppliedStickers', usecols=['Buff163 URL', 'Sticker URL Code', 'Sticker Price (Average)'])
    num_rows = len(excel_output.index)

    while(row_inc < num_rows):
        percentages = []

        stickerPrice = excel_output.at[row_inc, 'Sticker Price (Average)']
        adjustedPrices = returnDataBuff163(driver163, excel_output.at[row_inc, 'Buff163 URL'])

        listIncrement = 0

        while(listIncrement < len(adjustedPrices)):
            try:
                print(stickerPrice.text)
                percentages.append(round(adjustedPrices[listIncrement] / float(stickerPrice), 4))

            except:
                percentages.append("Error")
            listIncrement += 1

        if(percentages != False) :
            global percentagesDF
            percentagesDF = pd.DataFrame(percentages)
            startRow = 2
            startCol = 5

            with pd.ExcelWriter('MarketBots (1).xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
                percentagesDF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Buff163AppliedStickers', startrow=(startRow + row_inc), startcol=startCol)

        row_inc += 1

    driver163.quit()
```

Here is the error I get with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\StickerPercentage.py", line 185, in <module>
    start_buy_monitoring()
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\StickerPercentage.py", line 178, in start_buy_monitoring
    percentagesDF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Buff163AppliedStickers', startrow=(startRow + row_inc), startcol=startCol)
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2374, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 950, in write
    writer._write_cells(
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 496, in _write_cells
    xcell.value, fmt = self._value_with_fmt(cell.val)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only
```

Comment: The error you show `AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only` happens when you attempt to write to the no longer existing cells of a merge. For example if you merge cells `A1` and `B1` together that cell now has the coords `A1` and the cell `B1` no longer exists. If you attempted to write to cell `B1` you would get that error.

Comment: Why not simply read the output excel file as a `dict` using `pandas`, modify the array of dict and then write the output file *(with the same name so it overrides)*?

Comment: It would be easiest to avoid Pandas altogther for this.